# How to get 360 video by Youtube API (HTTP request)?

Tags: video, youtube-api

I'm working on Youtube-api here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

but I can't find any parameter to get 360 video list by HTTP request.
I want to get 360 video with the q parameter is "Ronaldo" (for example)

Does anyone know how to get 360 video by HTTP request or another solution to get 360 video ?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [blog](https://techcrunch.com/2016/04/18/youtube-rolls-out-support-for-360-degree-live-streams-and-spatial-audio/), YouTube will begin supporting [360-degree live](https://www.buzzfeed.com/brendanklinkenberg/youtube-developing-live-360-degree-video-capability?utm_term=.hk7EL2D2G#.caA43QaQP) streaming on its service. However the ability to read the pan/tilt coordinates isn't currently supported. There is no mention of [360 degree video](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6395969?hl=en&ref_topic=2888648) players in the documentation. Found this [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7547&q=reporter%3Asmartsystemdesign&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary) ticket how to embbed 360 degree video control.

Here's a documentation for YouTube 360:https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853702